# how to multiply slice an array using lodash javascript library

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

```
this.listSelectProjectStages = _.map(
                        _.values(_.get(map, 'PROJECT_STAGE', [])).slice(0, 5),
                        (e) => ({
                            value: e?.name,
                            label: e?.label,
                        })
                    );
```

as per the above lodash mapping the values from index 0 to 5 is fetched from PROJECT_STAGE array and pushe to the 'this.listSelectProjectStages' variable. I have a requirement change. I want to get 0 to 5 index and also last two values of the particular array and push to the 'this.listSelectProjectStages' variable. please help me.? how can I manipulate this code for that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, store the array in a variable:

```js
let arr = _.values(_.get(map, 'PROJECT_STAGE', []));
```

Then, use `slice` and `concat` to get the relevant parts:

```js
_.map(arr.slice(0,5).concat(arr.slice(-2)), e => ({value: e?.name, label: e?.label}));
```